How to resolve 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied error in iis docker container?
I have hosted a sample index.html site within an IIS Docker container on my Windows Server. I assigned the domain check.vault.info to the HTML site inside the Docker container. Additionally, I configured Application Request Routing (ARR) as a reverse proxy in my local IIS instance to redirect traffic from check.vault.info to the IIS Docker container.
While the setup has been completed successfully, accessing the check.vault.info domain results in the following error.
Error:
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
Interestingly, I followed the same steps on a local machine IIS setup, and it worked without any issues. Anybody know how resolve this issue i faced ?
